# Oracle connection in SAS

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I am using this oracle connection code in sas and getting this error:

> ```
> ORACLE prepare error: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'get_pat_fix';
> ```

my code looks like this:

```
proc sql;
 connect to oracle(user='XXXXX'orapw='XXXXXX'path='');

  create table work.XXX as select * from connection to oracle (

        select to_char(yy.XXXX) as XXXXXX,
substr(get_pat_fix ('XX', yy.XXXX , 'XX','XX'),1,5)   XXXX,
from XXX;
```

I have tried to modify it several times but could not get it fixed.
I would extremely appreciate your help regarding the same.

Comment: We'll need to see the declaration of get_pat_fix.

Comment: get_pat_fix is a function which takes a number of arguments or parameters.  The error message clearly indicates that the arguments you have included don't match the function's spec.  So, look at the functions's signature and make sure that the *number* and *data type* of the values and columns match what is expected.

Comment: The code as written also has two syntax errors outside of what is occuring in the get_pat_fix function.  First, you need to drop the comma on the second line of the SELECT statement since it is the last variable selected.  Second, you need to put in a close parenthesis ")" before the semicolon on the FROM statement.

Comment: Thanks you all for replying. As suggested I have fixed the syntax errors but I didnt understand the get_pat_fix function explanation. I think the declaration would help: substr(get_pat_fix ('CO', data.pat_ID, 'BL', '00'),1,5)dg0,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I didnt understand the get_pat_fix function explanation."

Browse the function in an IDE like TOAD or SQL Developer, or describe it in SQL*Plus like this:

```
SQL> desc validate_salary
FUNCTION validate_salary RETURNS VARCHAR2
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 P_CURRENT_SAL                  NUMBER                  IN
 P_RAISE_PCT                    NUMBER                  IN
 P_JOB                          VARCHAR2                IN
 P_HIREDATE                     DATE                    IN
 P_DEPTNO                       NUMBER                  IN     DEFAULT

SQL>
```

This shows you the *number* and *datatype* of the parameters.  We must pass values for every paramater which doesn't have a default, and we must pass a variable for any OUT or IN OUT parameter.  The passed values must match the datatype of the parameter.

Parameters can be passed by position...

```
SQL> select validate_salary (4000, 10, 'MGR', sysdate-720)
  2  from dual
  3  /

VALIDATE_SALARY(4000,10,'MGR',SYSDATE-720)
--------------------------------------------------------------
okay

SQL>
```

... or by named notation...

```
SQL> select validate_salary (p_current_sal=> e.sal
  2                              , p_hiredate=> e.hiredate
  3                              , p_deptno => e.deptno
  4                              , p_job => e.job
  5                              , p_raise_pct=> 10 )
  6  from emp e
  7  /

VALIDATE_SALARY(P_CURRENT_SAL=>E.SAL,P_HIREDATE=>E.HIREDATE,P_DEPTNO=>E.DEPTNO,P
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
okay
okay
okay  
...
```

Either way, the parameters need to match:

```
SQL> select validate_salary (4000, 10, 'MGR')
  2  from dual
  3  /
select validate_salary (4000, 10, 'MGR')
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'VALIDATE_SALARY'

SQL> select validate_salary (4000, 'MGR', sysdate-720, 40)
  2  from dual
  3  /
select validate_salary (4000, 'MGR', sysdate-720, 40)
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'VALIDATE_SALARY'


SQL>
```

---

Of course, I missed out the most obvious answer: consult your application's documentation, which will have a detailed description of the GET_PAT_FIX() function including its signature.  :-D  Sorry, thought I could keep a straight face while I typed that.

Alas, in the real world too many of us have to struggle along without decent documentation for our apps.  So we have to interrogate the database schema.   I don't think there are any SAS tools for doing this (the [ones Google throws up](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sas%20database%20browse) all seem to be just data browsers).  So that means you'll need a database tool.  I'm going to suggest Oracle's SQL Developer not because it's the best (that's a matter of taste) but because it is free, and it works.  [Find it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Thanks so so much. This is awesome and a great explanation. :). Just one more question, if you cant see the data, (as in my case you have to get data directly from oracle database) then how would I know the type or number of arguments because in my original code I have couple of more substr(get_....) statements after the get_pat _fix with same number of arguments but the error is in just this one? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Or is there a way to import or see oracle data (using proc contents) in sas? I dont have SAS access so I cant import it. I know I am asking too many questions but I am not familiar with this at all. I really appreciate all your help. Thanks a ton

Comment: Thanks APC. I appreciate your time.